# Can I limit a page's used number of processes on an Apache server

Tags: django, apache, server

I have a webpage that I would like to be limited to using just one process on an Apache server that has multiple processes. Can I limit that one webpage to using just one process while allowing the remaining pages on this server to use multiple processes? Would this be bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can limit the network speed of requests for specific uri's and virtualhosts with mod_ratelimit.

You can check the module docs at [mod_ratelimit doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html)